# Adding more tempdb data files gives more write latency

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tempdb

I am facing problems with tempdb please help and provide your suggestions.

Initially, I have found tempdb contention problem in my server (Sql server) by using [Simple talk Script](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/optimizing-tempdb-configuration-with-sql-server-2012-extended-events/). By using that script results i have found tempdb contention is existed. So i have started adding more tempdb files. I have added 8 files since i have 24 logical cores.

I have used below query to find cpu count.

```
SELECT cpu_count,hyperthread_ratio FROM [sys].[dm_os_sys_info]
```

It returns

Cpu_Count-24
hyperthread_ratio -6

After i have added more tempdb data files it resolves tempdb contention problem. I used to monitor Write/Read latency of each Database regularly.

Now i am seeing more write latency in tempdb it is in multiplies of 1000 for all files.

Before adding files i have never seen tempdb latency like above mentioned in my sql server

I have used [Paul Randal script](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-to-examine-io-subsystem-latencies-from-within-sql-server/) to monitor latency.

So please help me to solve this problem. Why latency is more?. Is anything wrongly i did?

Note:- Data files(All databases) are located in one separate drive.

Comment: Perhaps your IO subsystem cannot handle the load you are throwing at it. Check the disk queue lengths in PMON.